# HL-L2370DW printer randomly stops responding

Tags: printer, network-printer, brother-printer

I have an L2370DW printer from Brother, which is common desktop laser printer. I am using it in network mode via wifi.

I have disabled the eco settings as much as possible. Deep sleep is disabled and sleep timer is 50 min.

Occasionally I will try to print from this printer and the job will stay in "printing" status for a long time, with no document printed. This happens from both Mac and Linux computers. Sometimes a Linux PC will be able to print while Mac fails. The printer is not ignoring the print request, as typically many hours later the documents will be printed after all. The problem is not size and complexity of the document as it happens with trivial test docs as well.

During this, the printer will generally say "sleep" in its LCD display, but the printer's Web UI is responding. Pressing the "go" button on the printer does not make it print. Printing a test page using the printer's own display can sometimes wake it up, but usually the test pages come out and nothing else. Printing a test page from the computer's printer properties sometimes helps (after the test page is printed, the actual document will tend to be printed) but most of the time the test page fails to be printed also. Updating the drivers did not help. Deleting the printer and reinstalling it tends to help, but it is tedious to reinstall the printer every time I need a document printed.

Is there any solution or workaround for this problem?

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can’t disable deep sleep. Have you reviewed this troubleshooting guide? https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/151825/~/unable-to-print-after-the-machine-has-entered-deep-sleep---windows in addition, there have been known firmware issues causing this issue in the past. Two things you should do are update to the latest printer firmware and set a static IP address.

Comment: What happens if you wake the printer, and then restart the print queue?

Comment: @Appleoddity There is an option in the printer's menu to turn off deep sleep, and indeed it never goes to deep sleep after doing that. But it still goes to just "sleep". That link is unfortunately for Windows only, not sure what to do on Linux or Mac - they don't have a port setting.

Comment: @hdhondt What do you mean by waking the printer?

Comment: Just press the Go button on the printer.